# Table not updated after addition

Tags: ios, core-data

I want my app to check the core data store at start-up. If the store is empty, it will add two items into it.  What is the best way to implement this?

Can I put the following code in viewDidLoad?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MonitorItem"];
    self.monitorItemArray = [[managedObjectContext
                              executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                              error:nil] mutableCopy];

    // If the core data is empty, populate it with the two compulsory items
    if ([self.monitorItemArray count] == 0)
    {
        self.AddMandatoryItems;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I have searched other articles but none seems to give me an answer that I could understand.

Comment: Why are you using `reloadData` in `viewDidLoad`? It is used after when you get the data from any `webService` or any other `request`. If you wanna enter two items in `tableView`, add two objects in an `array` and use that array in `dataSource` of `tableView`. After that, if you are able to get `response`, empty that `array` and fill the `array` with `response objects` and then use `reloadData`.

Comment: Ok I will delete the reloadData. So I should just add the two items directly into self.monitorItemArray, right?

Comment: declare an array in your interface file, then in `viewDidLoad`, specify two items in that array, create `tableView` and use that array as the `dataSource`. After that, populate the data from the core data, and if there is some data, store that object in previous array after deleting older values and use `reloadData`

Answer (score 1):

Getting information from `managedObjectContext` in `viewDidLoad` is good.

If in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you populate the cells from `self.monitorItemArray` than there is no reason to call `reloadData` (Which essentially erase the entire table view and re-draw it from scratch - which is exactly what happens when the view is appearing on screen any way...).

If you **also** show information from a web service, you can call `reloadData` in the response method to **replace** the existing data with the one that came from the web. Otherwise - if only information from core data is shown on the table view - no need for `reloadData` (Or maybe only in a case where the information in your `managedObjectContext` has changed while the table view is on screen).